# DataTables cannot read property 'row' of undefined

Tags: javascript, datatables

I try to show my new data in table after update gets successful but it returning

> Cannot read property 'row' of undefined

## Code

`Script`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var table = $("#dataTableLocations").DataTable();
        $('#dataTableLocations').on('click', '.locationUpdate', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var ordID = $(this).data('id');
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');

            var province_id = $(this).closest("form").find("#province_idLocationUpdate").val();
            var city_id = $(this).closest("form").find("#city_idLocationUpdate").val();
            var name = $(this).closest("form").find("#nameLocUpdate").val();
            var address = $(this).closest("form").find("#addressLocationUpdate").val();
            var postalCode = $(this).closest("form").find("#postalCodeUpdate").val();
            var seqNo = $(this).closest("form").find("#seqNoUpdate").val();

            $.ajax({
                type:'PUT',
                url:'{{url('dashboard/customer-locations')}}/'+ordID,
                data:{
                    province_id:province_id,
                    city_id:city_id,
                    name:name,
                    address:address,
                    postalCode:postalCode,
                    seqNo:seqNo
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('check data', data); // see the screenshot below
                    console.log('check row', row); // see the screenshot below



                    table.cell( row, 0 ).data( data.data.seqNo );
                    table.cell( row, 1 ).data( data.data.name );
                    table.cell( row, 2 ).data( data.data.customer.name );
                    table.cell( row, 3 ).data( data.data.province.name );
                    table.cell( row, 4 ).data( data.data.city.name );
                    table.cell( row, 5 ).data( data.data.address );
                    table.cell( row, 6 ).data( data.data.postalCode );
                    $('.editModalLocation').modal('hide');
                    $(".customerMessage").append('<div class="alert alert-success fade in">'+data.success+'</div>').hide(4000);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

`Table`

```
<table id="dataTableLocations" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30">Seq No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Province</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Postal Code</th>
        <th width="120">Options</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_dataLocations"></tbody>
</table>
```

## Screenshot

[image: one]

**Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solved

I moved my update code to parent script where the data was returning and merged them all in one now my code works as it supposed to.

Comment: Your question was nicely detailed, but this answer is really lacking. Any chance you could show users with the same question how you solved your issue?

Comment: @oxwilder my data was coming from ajax request, and I moved my update ajax in success function of data ajax. `ajax getData() {success: show data; update data;}` get it? Update ajax is inside get ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Try change this:

> var row = $(this).closest('tr')

change to

> var row = table.row(this);

Comment: Keep it, and try to this row: $('#dataTableLocations').on('click', '.locationUpdate', function(e) --> $('#dataTableLocations tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e)

Comment: no that didn't work either, the strange thing is that i have exactly same function 10 lines above for different data updates and that works just fine

Comment: Is table dataTableLocations initialize to DataTable success and you don't have duplicated ID anywhere?

Comment: I don't know why red message appear after console.log, while row variable in your scrip before console.log. it's not correct!. You should to make sure variable name not duplicate too. Don't using "var" to declare variable just use "let" to declare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205282/discussion-between-phong-nguyn-and-mafortis).